# How to create android navbar?

Tags: android, templates, layout, tabs, nav

I've tried following guides with ViewPager and slidingtablayout but they don't seem to work or are deprecated. Now what is the actual best way to create tabs on an android template?

Or can someone point me to a guide/tutorial with a simple clear explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Creating tabs can be done very easily with a library that was made for just that:

[astuetz' PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

Add the dependancy to your app's (NOT project's) build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
}
```

Include a PagerSlidingTabStrip widget to your layout (XML), this is typically placed above the `ViewPager` it represents:

```
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
android:id="@+id/tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dip" />
```

Create a ViewPager adapter:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * TabsPagerAdapter.
 *
 * @author Niels
 * @version 1.0
 * @since 11-9-2015
 */
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    /**
     * Contains all the fragments.
     */
    private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Contains all the tab titles.
     */
    private List<String> tabTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Creates a new PagerAdapter instance.
     *
     * @param fragmentManager The FragmentManager.
     */
    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles.get(position);
    }

    /**
     * Adds the fragment to the list, also adds the fragment's tab title.
     *
     * @param fragment New instance of the Fragment to be associated with this tab.
     * @param tabTitle A String containing the tab title for this Fragment.
     */
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String tabTitle) {
        fragments.add(fragment);
        tabTitles.add(tabTitle);
    }

}
```

And finally, in your activity's onCreate:

```
    //adapter = view.findViewById(...)
    //viewpager = view.findViewById(...)
    adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentTab1() "Tab 1");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentTab2(), "Tab 2");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentTab3(), "Tab 3");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentTab4(), "Tab 4");
    viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
    strip.setViewPager(viewpager);
```